# preg_replace... remove string from string

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

What I want to do is remove all instances of c_*/ where * could be any digit or character of any length.

```
$cano = 'www.example.com/example/example2/c_3/example4/';
$cano = preg_replace('c_*/', '', $cano);
```

I've always been bad with these cause I hardly use them...

Comment: Did my answer help at all? I can alter it if it's not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do the trick.

```
$cano = preg_replace('#c_[^/]+/#', '', $cano);
```

The `[^/]` matches any character that is not a forward slash, and the `+` means "one or more" characters.

Comment: thanks... worked great... threw it into an array with some others and working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$cano = 'www.example.com/example/example2/c_3/example4/';
$cano = preg_replace('#(?:c_.[^/]/)+#', '', $cano);
```